# Displaying posts sorting by a custom criterion

Tags: sort, order

I wish to display my posts, not according to the date, but to a completely custom criterion. Ideally, I would manually set a numerical value to each post and the WP loop would display posts according to this value.

So if post X has value 1, post Y has value 2 and Z value 3, it would display first X, then Y, than Z, even though the date criterion would entail a different order. Hope it makes sense.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the order in a [Custom Field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), then modify the main query to order on that custom field via [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). Example for posts page:

```
function wpa_custom_order( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'your_order_key' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_custom_order' );
```

Comment: and how would I display the posts in reverse order?

Comment: @MichaelWiles [set the `order` parameter to `ASC` to reverse order (default is `DESC`)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: thank you. Yes, I got all the information I needed :)